# margin changes by selecting different options

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$('#cpseltop').change(function() {
 var a = $(this).val();
 $('.cpselhide').hide();
 $('#cpsel' + a).show();
});
```

```css
.cpselect{
 display:block;
 border:1px solid #999;
 border-radius:9px;
 outline:none;
 width:100%;
 padding:2px 5px;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:12px;
 margin:7px auto;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

.cpselauth, .cpselmoder{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='cpselect cpseltop' id='cpseltop'>
<option value='status'>STATUS</option>
<option value='auth'>AUTHORS</option>
<option value='moder'>MODERS</option>
</select>

<select class='cpselect cpselstatus cpselhide' id='cpselstatus'>
<option value='all' data-max=54>ALL</option>
</select>

<select class='cpselect cpselauth cpselhide' id='cpselauth'>
<option value='all'>ALL</option>
</select>

<select class='cpselect cpselmoder cpselhide' id = 'cpselmoder'>
<option value='all'>ALL</option>
</select>
```

Selecting `AUTHORS` and `MODERS` the margin between `cpseltop` and the next one is larger compared if I select `STATUS` !

Why this happens?

Comment: @puerto It's because `.show()` sets `display: inline-block`, which causes the margins of the elements to no longer overlap. If you use `css("display", "block")` instead, it works fine.

Comment: @ChrisG, are you sure? Why this happens only on specific option?

Comment: It is due to `$('#cpsel' + a).show();` which happens to be on a `display:none;` Element, due to the className. So, it shows the Element that is not displayed, including margins.

Comment: @puerto Yes, I'm sure. I used the inspector to check the elements, and if a hidden element is in between, a `block` and an `inline-block` element didn't have overlapping margins. That's why STATUS behaves differently, because it's directly after the first `<select>`. Are you not using the inspector for debugging...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing a  [margin-collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) issue. When Status is selected you show the `select` tag that is the **next** after the main one with a `display:block` and since both elements are adjacent their margin collapse. But it's not the case for the other `select` since there are set to `display:inline-block` when shown so their margin doesn't collapse with first one.

To fix this you may consider only one margin (top or bottom) or change the style of `.cpselect` to be `display:inline-block`:

```js
$('#cpseltop').change(function() {
 var a = $(this).val();
 $('.cpselhide').hide();
 $('#cpsel' + a).show();
});
```

```css
.cpselect{
 display:inline-block;
 border:1px solid #999;
 border-radius:9px;
 outline:none;
 width:100%;
 padding:2px 5px;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:12px;
 margin:7px 0;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

.cpselauth, .cpselmoder{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='cpselect cpseltop' id='cpseltop'>
<option value='status'>STATUS</option>
<option value='auth'>AUTHORS</option>
<option value='moder'>MODERS</option>
</select>
<select class='cpselect cpselstatus cpselhide' id='cpselstatus'>
<option value='all' data-max=54>ALL</option>
</select>
<select class='cpselect cpselauth cpselhide' id='cpselauth'>
<option value='all'>ALL</option>
</select>
<select class='cpselect cpselmoder cpselhide' id = 'cpselmoder'>
<option value='all'>ALL</option>
</select>
```

Comment: but if some tag is hidden, the next one should be adjacent !

Comment: @puerto yes am updating, i made a mistake